# Show Loading Message in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to show a loading indicator in my asp.net webpage while my gridview is being filled with data

This is part of my aspx page

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jsUpdateProgress.js"></script>      
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Panel ID="panelUpdateProgress" runat="server" CssClass="updateProgress">
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProg1" DisplayAfter="0" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div style="position: relative; top: 30%; text-align: center;">
                    <img src="Styles/images/loading.gif" style="vertical-align: middle" alt="Processing" />
                    Loading...
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </asp:Panel>
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalProgress" runat="server" TargetControlID="panelUpdateProgress"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="panelUpdateProgress" />
```

(My code is based on this sample weblogs.asp.net/blogs/guillermo/Code/modalExample.zip)

This is my button to call my method

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btMonth" runat="server" onclick="btMonth_Click" Text="Ver" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is my c# code of my method btMonth_Click

```
    protected void btMonth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "select * from table";
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = query;
    gInd.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
}
```

As you can see while the "Loading" indicator appears I want to fill a GridView, but when I make click in my button the method btMonth_Click is invoked, the method is executed but my gridview doesn't get filled. If I remove the asp:UpdatePanel of my button my gridview is filled fine

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: call the grid view databind method in button event handler

Comment: where is gridview ? inside or outside of update panel ?

Comment: Let the button and the gridview on the same UpdatePanel.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua forgot to mention, my gridview is outside of update panel, it has to be inside?

Comment: @NatyBizz yes, it should be inside the same update panel as button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place your `GridVew` inside of your `UpdatePanel` in order to be partial rendered

If for design reasons you cannot place your grid inside the *first* `UpdatePanel`, you can have several `UpdatePanel`

For more info:

[How to work with two update panels on same .aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11358141/1268570)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
gInd.DataBind();
```

in your btMonth_Click
(Btw. better naming convencion would be btnMonth_Click)

```
    protected void btMonth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "select * from table";
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = query;
    gInd.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
    gInd.DataBind();
}
```