# ASP.NET page freezes when using two update panels

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have two update panels on my ASP.NET page.

First UpdatePanel has a Label and a timer control which is set to tick on every second.
Second UpdatePanel is for rest of the page which has many dynamically added buttons. Number of buttons to be added on page depends on the situation, so can not be added statically. also as these buttons are added dynamically i have add them on every postback.

The application runs perfectly fine with satisfactory response time. but in some rare cases application freezes. (In my opinion its running into deadlock because of two update panels updating at the same time)

Will threading resolve this  issue? if Yes Kindly point me to good tutorial or solution if no then please suggest a solution.

Your response is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please refer the link below..

[How to work with two update panels on same .aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358141/how-to-work-with-two-update-panels-on-same-aspx-page)

Hope it helps..!!

To know more about Updatepanel control go through the below link..!

http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/

And below is the UpdatePanel update mode documentation of Microsoft

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx