# asp.net: timer triggers not the correct updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, timer, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have three  elements which have to be updated every five seconds.

```
<div id="dLogout"><asp:Button ID="bLogout" runat="server" OnClick="bLogout_Click" Text="Logout" /></div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="TimerUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer runat="server" id="tTimer" Interval="5000" OnTick="UpdateTimer_Tick" />
            <div id="dLastExport"   runat="server">Last export: {0}</div>
            <div id="dOnSale"       runat="server">On sale: {0}</div>
            <div id="dToBeExported" runat="server">To be exported: {0}</div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tTimer" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

After this code snippet there are more updatepanels. When the OnTick event is triggered, all updatepanels() seem to update. This causes my webpage to look ugly each 5 seconds. I have only one timer.

How can I specify that only the content between "TimerUpdatePanel" updates?

Best regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358141/how-to-work-with-two-update-panels-on-same-aspx-page

Comment: yes, you are right. I red that post, but I think there is a problem with the timer. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You can set your updatepanel behaviour. To update with every other udpate panel, or to udpate conditionally.

Comment: i havent encountered any problem with asp timer so far, you can however, change your trigger to ' <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="tTimer"/>' and see if it helps

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't. I supposed that maybe any id's are not unique, but this seems all ok. when I remove the updatepanel from the code, everything works as expected. That's why I guess it must have something to do with the timer or a missing dependency between the timer and the updatepanel "TimerUpdatePanel".

Comment: @LouisvanTonder: Thank you very much. I added UpdateMode="Conditional" to the other updatepanel and now everything seem to work properly. Thank you guys!

Comment: @user3180943 Glad you're sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your updatepanel behaviour. To update with every other udpate panel, or to udpate conditionally.