# Update panel not working in two asp panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

In my ascx page I have two panel,I trying to change these panels inside an update panel.but the page load is going on each click on radio button.here is my code

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" >
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="radioListAnswers"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" onselectedindexchanged="radioListAnswers_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
</asp:Panel>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="radioListAnswers" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="false">
<div> Thanks</div>
</asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

here is my code behind

```
void radioListAnswers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel2.Visible=false;
panel1.Visible=true;
    }
```

on click on each radio button the page is reloading.How can we over come this.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Remove the `Autopostback="True"` from your radio button.

Comment: @CoderofCode I Removed the Autopostback .but it not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this will help. Pls check this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398867(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Hi Veena,
Ithu nokkiyatha but kittunnilla ....    :)

I need to change visibility of the panel by click on the radio button.

Comment: so, do u need to change the visibility of panel1 based on radio button index change?

Comment: I just done 

panel2.visible=false;
panel1.visible=true;

inside radiobutton seleted indexchange

Comment: just post it here pls

Comment: Hi Veena,
 I just Edit the question. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358141/how-to-work-with-two-update-panels-on-same-aspx-page

Comment: Veena,

Nice example,Actually this was my problem and it is solved..thanks for your help...